# Proving the Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $N$ $\leq$ M, prove that ($G$/$N$)/($M$/$N$) $\approx$ $G/M$.

What I have so far:

We can define a mapping $\phi$: $G/N$ $\mapsto$ $G/H$ by $\phi$($gN$)=$gH$. We must first check that $\phi$ is well-defined.

Let $\phi$($aN$)=$aM$.

If $aN$=$bN$, then $b^{-1}$$a$ $\in$ $N$ $\subseteq$ $M$ and so $aM=bM$.

Now we must show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Suppose that $aN$, $bN$ $\in$  $G$/$N$.

Then $\phi$ (($a$)($bN$))=($abN$)

=$abM$
=($aM$)($bM$)

=$\phi$ ($aN$)$\phi$ ($bN$)

Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: That's right so far. Next: Work out the kernel of $\phi$ and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Also check the surjectivity of the homomorphism which is easy to see